# Magento-2 : How to add custom template just before add to cart button on product detail page

Tags: layout, product-view, magento2.2.2, custom-template

I want to display my custom template just before add to cart button on product detail page.

It should be display in all type of product like **Bundle**, **Grouped,** **Configurable** Product.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution by core layout reference, I have displayed my custom template just before add to cart button in all types of product by below code

> app/code/Namespace/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.custom.simple" template="Namespace_ModuleName::product/view/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.custom.additional" template="Namespace_ModuleName::product/view/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Namespace/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.bundle">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.custom.bundle.additional" template="Namespace_ModuleName::product/view/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```